# How to configure a Listener to override the behaviour of the class LoggingReporter in Citrus?

Tags: citrus-framework

I'm looking for a way to remove stacktraces of fails assertions when using the framework **Citrus**.

This is done in **testNg** like this:

```
public class NoStackTraceListener implements ITestListener {
...
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult iTestResult) {
    Throwable th = iTestResult.getThrowable();
    if (Objects.nonNull(th)) {
        System.out.println(th.getMessage());
        iTestResult.setThrowable(null);
    }
}
...
}

@Listeners({ NoStackTraceListener.class })
class A {...}
```

But I can't find any example of usgin the class 'TestListener' or others in order to override the supplied implementation of 'LoggingReporter'

Please do anyone has already overrided a **Listener** using **framework citrus** and could give the snippet to do so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the custom reporter as bean to the Spring application context:

```
@Bean
public NoStackTraceReporter noStackTraceReporter() {
    return new NoStackTraceReporter();
}
```

You can also overwrite the default logging reporter by choosing the bean name `loggingReporter`

```
@Bean
public NoStackTraceReporter loggingReporter() {
    return new NoStackTraceReporter();
}
```

The `NoStackTraceReporter` implementation is then able to overwrite the specific event handler for failed tests:

```
public class NoStackTraceReporter extends LoggingReporter {
...
    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(TestCase test, Throwable cause) {
        // do something customized
    }
...
}
```

Also you may overwrite the `generateTestResults()` method in the reporter interface in order to customize logging results.

You can also follow the sample http://www.citrusframework.org/samples/reporting/ that demonstrates how to add customized reporters in Citrus.